# Why does rails jquery-ujs prevent forms with non-empty files from submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using Rails 4 server with jquery-rails plugin. I have stumbled upon this issue, whereby if my form with `data-remote="true"` contains file inputs, an attempt to submit it raises an `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error. Turns out that `jquery_ujs.js` aborts all its preprocessing of the form, including populating CSRF tokens, if it finds any non-empty file input. My original approach was using a `FileReader` on the browser side to read the contents of the file into a hidden input. Now it turns out that in addition to that hack I need to set the value of the file input to blank after the read is complete.

Two questions therefore.

A - are there any inherent flaws with my approach of reading the file contents into a hidden input and submitting it via ajax (security breach?).

B - should this behaviour of `jquery-rails` that causes a CSRF error be considered a bug?